# How to set a specific input method to emacs specific major-mode if I have a condition?

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I need to set Russian input method if I open a line from po-mode and only from po-mode. The line opens in txt-mode in which default is English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
(setq default-input-method "russian-computer")
(add-hook 'po-mode-hook #'toggle-input-method)
```

You can manually toggle the input method with `M-x toggle-input-method` or `C-\`.

Get a list of available input methods with `M-x list-input-methods`.